# MongoDB C# driver: waiting for replication timed out

Tags: c#, mongodb

I use MongoDB 3.0.3 and the C# driver 1.10.0.62.
I have 2 shards and set the `writeConcern: W = 2, WTimeout = 5000`
When I use the method `col.Insert(data, writeConcern)` the program always throw exceptions as below:
`MongoDB.Driver.MongoWriteConcernException: WriteConcern detected an error 'waiting for replication timed out at shard01'. (Response was { "ok" : 1, "code" : 64, "err" : "waiting for replication timed out at shard01", "n" : NumberLong(0) }).`
These exceptions occurs frequently. Does anyone know how to handle them??